# How to get a record count using Native SQL in conjunction with Entity Framework, ExecuteStoreQuery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-6

I am using MVC3. Asp.Net 4.5, EF6, SQL Server 2008

I need to use Native SQL to get a count of records from a table that satisfies a certain condition.

I believe I need ExecuteStoreQuery. I have tried the following code, but get cast exceptions.

```
int RecordCount = (int)db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Int32>("select count(*) from myTable where RecordType = '{0}' and ParentId={1}", "MyRecordType", 1);
```

Some silly code error no doubt. Guidance/Correction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use EF to return a count of records, use ADO.net.  EF is meant for returning entities/objects from the db.

Comment: OK, thanks for this. Do you have a code example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an ado.net example from Microsoft.
[MS Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is a C# example

```
    static public int AddProductCategory(string newName, string connString)
    {
        Int32 rowCount = 0;
        string sql = "select count(*) from myTable where RecordType = '@recordType' and ParentId=@parentid;";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@recordType", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@recordType"].Value = "MyRecordType";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@parentid", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@parentid"].Value = 1;
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                rowCount = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return (int)rowCount;
    }
```

Comment: Np, after looking at my post, there is obvious cleanup to be done to the code, but will get you close.